# How to count views of blog in django

Tags: python, django, http, counting

I am trying to count and show all views in every blog in my django project. What is the best way to do that? (Pardon mistakes)

Comment: You need to share your models.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach you could take, assuming that you want to update a post view count each time that post has been viewed by a viewer.

You can add an `integer field` on the `Post model`. This field on a post can be updated when that post has been viewed.

You can also add a `method` on the `Post model` that will specifically update the view count whenever it is called, which can allow the post view count to be updated from the `hmtl` template itself *(not recommended)*, as well as in the `views` *(whether cbv or fbv)*.

Within the `models.py` file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     ...
     views = models.IntegerField(default=0) # Upon creation the views will be 0
     ...

    # You can have
    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('post-details', kwargs={"id": self.id})

    # An alternative to use to update the view count 
    def update_views(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.views = self.views + 1
         super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Within the *app* `urls.py` file:

```
from app.views import PostDetailsView, post_details

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    # Using either of the following
    path('post-details/<int:id>/', PostDetailsView.as_view(), name='post-details'), # class-based view
    path('post-details/<int:id>/', post_details, name='post-details'), # function-based view 
    ...
]
```

Within the `views.py` file:

```
# Class based view
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
     context_object_name = 'post'
     template_name = 'post-details.html'

     # Overriding the class get_object method
     def get_object(self):
          post_id = self.kwargs.get('id')
          post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

          # Update the view count on each visit to this post.
          if post:
               post.views = post.views + 1
               post.save()
   
               # Or
               post.update_views()

          return post

    # You might have other methods in here if necessary
    ...

# Function based view
def post_detail(request, id):
     post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)

     # Update the view count on each visit to this post.
      if post:
           post.views = post.views + 1
           post.save()

           # Or
           post.update_views()

     ...

     context = {
          'post': post,
           ...
     }

     return render(request, "post-details.html", context)
```